# Save persistent file in NaCl and read inside app JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

In my chrome app, I would like to save a persistent file in `NaCl` module (using `Pepper API` or `nacl_io`), then open and read it with JavaScript code inside the app.

The `NaCl` part is implemented by using `nacl_io` and works fine (with `html5fs` and `PERSISTENT` type).

How can I do the other part in JS code?

Comment: It would help if you include how you open the file for writing in NaCl.

Comment: Add that to the question itself, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the files in JavaScript using the [Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Here is an example of reading a file from that page:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {

  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Get a File object representing the file,
    // then use FileReader to read its contents.
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onloadend = function(e) {
         var txtArea = document.createElement('textarea');
         txtArea.value = this.result;
         document.body.appendChild(txtArea);
       };

       reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);

}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

In your case, you'll want to read from the PERSISTENT filesystem instead of the TEMPORARY filesystem.

Please note that this API is prefixed in Chrome as `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`.

Comment: But, it is not possible to use window.requestFileSystem in chrome apps even without writing "window." . I also tried "fs" with "chrome.fileSystem.". But, this time, I got error for "root" property definition. I think this code does not work in chrome apps and needs more changes . Am I right?

Comment: It should be available prefixed as window.webkitRequestFileSystem. I just ran a test using this function from a Chrome App and was able to get a valid FileSystem object.